# Is there a way to use eventData with .bind() with the "keydown" eventType?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to do something like:

```
var keydownHandler = function (ev) {
    alert(ev.data.test);
    return false;
}

$(document).bind('keydown', {test: 'foo'}, keydownHandler);
```

But the `.bind` does not seems to work as it returns `null` and pressing a key doesn't fire the handler. Replacing `keydown` with the "click" eventType, the event handler is correctly registered and works.

My current code uses an anonymous function like this:

```
var config = ...;
$(document).bind('keydown', config.shortcut, function (e) {
    config.click();
    e.stopPropagation( );
    e.preventDefault( );
}

return false;
} );
```

It works fine but I have to externalize the anonymous function and I don't see how I can pass the extra info required by it.

Comment: what do you mean by "externalize the anonymous function" ?

Comment: @LekisS I mean putting it out from the .bind() function so that I can reuse it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the [hotkeys plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys) is loaded which requires the **"combi"** parameter to be set:

```
var keydownHandler = function (ev) {
    alert(ev.data.test);
    return false;
}

$(document).bind('keydown', {combi: 'x', test: 'foo'}, keydownHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example you provided works for me (as shown in the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YFBsE).

If you want to extract your anonymous function (for example, to reuse it), and you need to pass data to the function which differs from use-case to use-case, you should consider using a method as shown below:

```
function buildHandler (data) {
    return function (event) {
      alert(data.test);

        return false;
    }; 
};

$(document).bind('keydown', buildHandler({ test: 'foo' }));
$(document).bind('click', buildHandler({ test: 'bar' }));
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8cvk/

Comment: I've found the source of the error, it also works for me on Fiddle, but it stops as soon as I add the [hotkeys plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys). Fiddle updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/YFBsE/1/